# Python increment values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to count every word from text files and appending the word and count to a dictionary as the key-value pairs. It throws me this error: if key not in wordDict:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Also, I am wondering of .split() is good because my text files contain different punctuation marks.

```
fileref = open(mypath + '/' + i, 'r')
wordDict = {}
for line in fileref.readlines():
    key = line.split()
    if key not in wordDict:
        wordDict[key] = 1
    else:
        wordDict[key] += 1
```

Comment: If you want to use an _additional_ seperator you could use `line.replace(other, ' ')` before you `split`.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import Counter
text = '''I am trying to count every word from text files and appending the word and count to a dictionary as the key-value pairs. It throws me this error: if key not in wordDict: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' Also, I am wondering of .split() is good because my text files contain different punctuation marks. Thanks ahead for those who help!'''

split_text = text.split()
counter = Counter(split_text)
print(counter)
```

out:

```
Counter({'count': 2, 'and': 2, 'text': 2, 'to': 2, 'I': 2, 'files': 2, 'word': 2, 'am': 2, 'the': 2, 'dictionary': 1, 'a': 1, 'not': 1, 'in': 1, 'ahead': 1, 'me': 1, 'trying': 1, 'every': 1, '.split()': 1, 'type:': 1, 'my': 1, 'punctuation': 1, 'is': 1, 'key': 1, 'error:': 1, 'help!': 1, 'those': 1, 'different': 1, 'throws': 1, 'TypeError:': 1, 'contain': 1, 'wordDict:': 1, 'appending': 1, 'if': 1, 'It': 1, 'Also,': 1, 'unhashable': 1, 'from': 1, 'because': 1, 'marks.': 1, 'pairs.': 1, 'this': 1, 'key-value': 1, 'wondering': 1, 'Thanks': 1, 'of': 1, 'good': 1, "'list'": 1, 'for': 1, 'who': 1, 'as': 1})
```

Comment: this example can be better with a multi-lines example, str.splitlines() can be used for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a list of space-delimited words found in the current line. You would need to iterate over that list as well.

```
for line in fileref:
    keys = line.split()
    for key in keys:
        if key not in wordDict:
            wordDict[key] = 1
        else:
            wordDict[key] += 1
```

---

This can be cleaned up considerably by either using the `setdefault` method or a `defaultdict` from the `collections` module; both allow you to avoid explicitly checking for a key by automatically adding the key with an initial value if it isn't already in the `dict`.

```
for key in keys:
    wordDict.setdefault(key, 0) += 1
```

or

```
from collections import defaultdict
wordDict = defaultdict(int)   # Default to 0, since int() == 0

...

   for key in keys:
       wordDict[key] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a list and you're trying to see if a list is in a dictionary which is equivalent to seeing if it is one of the keys. Dictionary keys canot be lists hence the "unhashable type" error.

Answer (score 0):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) return a list of words

```
>>> "hello world".split()
['hello', 'world']
>>>
```

and lists or any other mutable object cannot be used as a key of a dictionary, and that is why you get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

You need to iterate over it to include each one of those, also the recommended way to work with a [file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is with the [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)

```
wordDict = {}
with open(mypath + '/' + i, 'r') as fileref:
    for line in fileref:
        for word in line.split():
            if word not in wordDict:
                wordDict[word] = 1
            else:
                wordDict[word] += 1
```

the above can be shortened with the use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and an [appropriate](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) call to it

```
from collections import Counter

with open(mypath + '/' + i, 'r') as fileref:    
    wordDict = Counter( word for line in fileref for word in line.split() )
```